# sending http requests with specific/non-existent http version protocol in Python

Tags: python, urllib, httplib

There is some way to send http requests in python with specific http version protocol.I think that, with httplib or urllib, it is not possible.

For example: GET / HTTP/6.9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What do you hope to accomplish by sending an illegal version number?

Comment: HTTP fingerprinting, to obtain what version and model of web server is  running an toe.

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be "with httplib or urllib"? (Especially since the latter is deprecated?)

Comment: No, I had thought to do this with sockets, but someone said me "don't reinvent the wheel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is: You're right, neither [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection) nor [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) has public, built-in functionality to do this. (Also, you really shouldn't be using `urllib` for most things—in particular, for `urlopen`.)

Of course you can always rely on implementation details of those modules, as in [Lukas Graf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26874854/908494).

Or, alternatively, you could fork one of those modules and modify it, which guarantees that your code will work on other Python 2.x implementations.*. Note that `httplib` is one of those modules that has a link to [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/httplib.py) up at the top, which means it's mean to server as example code, not just as a black-box library.

Or you could just reimplement the lowest-level function that needs to be hooked but that's publicly documented. For `httplib`, I believe that's `httplib.HTTPConnection.putrequest`, which is a few hundred lines long.

Or you could pick a different library that has more hooks in it, so you have less to hook.

But really, if you're trying to craft a custom request to manually fingerprint the results, why are you using an HTTP library at all? Why not just do this?

```
msg = 'GET / HTTP/6.9\r\n\r\n'
s = socket.create_connection((host, 80))
with closing(s):
    s.send(msg)
    buf = ''.join(iter(partial(s.recv, 4096), ''))
```

<sub>* That's not much of a benefit, given that there will never be a 2.8, all of the existing major 2.7 implementations share the same source for this module, and it's not likely any new 2.x implementation will be any different. And if you go to 3.x, `httplib` has been reorganized and renamed, while `urllib` has been removed entirely, so you'll already have bigger changes to worry about.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily enough by subclassing [`httplib.HTTPConnection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection) and redefining the class attribute [`_http_vsn_str`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ee879c0ffa11/Lib/httplib.py#l683):

```
from httplib import HTTPConnection


class MyHTTPConnection(HTTPConnection):

    _http_vsn_str = '6.9'


conn = MyHTTPConnection("www.stackoverflow.com")
conn.request("GET", "/")
response = conn.getresponse()

print "Status: {} {}".format(response.status, response.reason)
print "Headers: {}".format(response.getheaders())
print "Body: {}".format(response.read())
```

Of course this will result in a `400 Bad Request` for most servers:

```
Status: 400 Bad Request
Headers: [('date', 'Tue, 11 Nov 2014 21:21:12 GMT'), ('connection', 'close'), ('content-type', 'text/html; charset=us-ascii'), ('content-length', '311')]
Body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: I don't like this.  That attribute's existence and purpose is not contractually guaranteed.  This could break in a future version of Python.

Comment: @Kevin well - you're changing the HTTP version identifier to `6.9` while still talking `HTTP 1.1`. No public API is going to ever support something this.

Comment: True... I suppose I'm really concerned that OP probably should not be trying to do exactly this in the first place.  Perhaps they should be using an entirely different technique.

Comment: @Kevin: Then the answer is, "No, you can't do this with the `httplib` in Python 2.7". But you can fork your own copy of `httplib` and modify or subclass that, in which case it _is_ guaranteed

Comment: @Kevin: Also, if you're using Python 2.7, anything that exists now is pretty much guaranteed to exist for as long as Python 2.x is supported, because there will never be a 2.8. (And if you go to 3.x, you already have to change a lot—`httplib` doesn't even exist under that name anymore.)

Comment: Yes, if HTTP fingerprinting is the purpose, this probably should be done on just a TCP socket level.

Comment: Also, W3C [suggests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) you'd see 505 HTTP Version Not Supported instead of 400 Bad Request.  This is desirable for forward compatibility, at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible using pycurl by using this option

```
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTP_VERSION, pycurl.CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0)
```

however you need to use linux or mac since pycurl is not officially supported on windows